# Compare two text files in Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl, file, text

I have several strings in two .txt file. Both of them contain some similar strings but are not arranged on the same line number.

For example,
file1.txt
Carmen 
Edison 
Molly
Jason
Damon 
Gerard

file2.txt 
Edison
Jason

I want to save the similar strings that found in both text files (in this case: Edison Jason) to an array.

Comment: We are here to help you finish your task, not to do it for you. Show us what you have and ask a more specific question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the need to use additional modules

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data1 = qw( Carmen Edison Molly Jason Damon Gerard );
my @data2 = qw( Edison Jason );
my @data3 = ();

foreach my $d1 ( @data1 )
{
    chomp $d1;

    foreach my $d2 ( @data2 )
    {
        chomp $d2;

        if( $d1 eq $d2 )
        {
            print "Match Found : $d1, $d2 \n";
            push @data3, $d1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various array utility libraries for achieving this - what your after specifically is intersection, Array::Utils being one of the simpler libraries to achieve this;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use Array::Utils qw(intersect);

my $file1 = 'file1.txt';
my $file2 = 'file2.txt';

my @data1 = split( /\s/, read_file($file1) );
my @data2 = split( /\s/, read_file($file2) );

my @intersect = intersect( @data1, @data2 );

print join(', ', @intersect), "\n";
```

Or, without requiring Array::Utils

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data1 = qw( Carmen Edison Molly Jason Damon Gerard );
my @data2 = qw( Edison Jason );

sub intersect {
  my %e = map { $_ => undef } @{$_[0]};
  return grep { exists( $e{$_} ) } @{$_[1]};
}

my @intersect = intersect( \@data1, \@data2 );
print join(', ', @intersect), "\n";
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me as my linux can't locate Array/Utils.pm. I am using my company pc to work on this.

Comment: you will need to install Array::Utils, from the command line `sudo cpan Array::Utils', or simply copy the intersect sub from https://github.com/salmonix/Analictica_perl/blob/master/AUtils/ArrayUtils.pm#L102

Comment: the command says I am not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/cpan Array::Utils'
Is there another way to write the code?

Comment: Yes, copy the sub from the link in my previous comment into your code and remove the reference to Array::Utils in the example

Comment: Didn't work as well. I have tried Text::Diff but never work like I wanted.

Comment: The updated example works for me, let me know what error you get.

Comment: It always shows package not included or not allowed to execute certain codes

Comment: I've simplified the second example, it should work without any dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way without installing any additional modules

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my (@file1,@file2,@match);

open FILE1, "<", 'file1.txt';
@file1 = <FILE1>;
close FILE1;

open FILE2, "<", 'file2.txt';
@file2 = <FILE2>;
close FILE2;

chomp (@file1,@file2);

foreach(@file1) {
    if ($_ ~~ @file2) {
        push @match, $_;
    }
}

print "\nMatches\n";
foreach(@match) { print "The same -- $_\n"; }
```